# Why is my VM instance's startup script not running?

Tags: python, shell, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-compute-engine

I am playing around with Compute Engine. I have written a Python script that calls the Compute Engine API and tries to create a VM instance with an accompanying start up script. The start up script is meant to create a simple HTML file using the echo command.

The Python script is creating the VM instance successfully. However, when I SSH into the VM instance there is no trace of the HTML file.

However, if I run the echo command manually in the secure shell...

```
echo "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1><p>This page was created from a startup scri
pt.</p></body></html>" > index.html
```

...the file is successfully created.

Why is this not working in my start up script? Is there something I need to tweak in the Python code below?

```
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

def create_instance(compute, project, zone, name):
    # Get the latest Debian Jessie image.
    image_response = (
        compute.images()
        .getFromFamily(project="debian-cloud", family="debian-9")
        .execute()
    )
    source_disk_image = image_response["selfLink"]

    # Configure the machine
    machine_type = "zones/%s/machineTypes/n1-standard-1" % zone
    config = {
        "name": name,
        "machineType": machine_type,
        # Specify the boot disk and the image to use as a source.
        "disks": [
            {
                "boot": True,
                "autoDelete": True,
                "initializeParams": {
                    "sourceImage": source_disk_image,
                },
            }
        ],
        "networkInterfaces": [
            {
                "network": "global/networks/default",
                "accessConfigs": [{"type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT", "name": "External NAT"}],
            }
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "kind": "compute#metadata",
 "items": [
      {
        "key": "startup-script",
        "value": 'sudo apt-get update\nexport DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive\necho "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1><p>This page was created from a startup script.</p></body></html>" > index.html'
      }
    ]
        },
        "tags": {"items": ["http-server", "https-server"]},
    }

    return compute.instances().insert(project=project, zone=zone, body=config).execute()


create_instance(service, project_id, zone, "pandora-instance")
```

Comment: Try replacing `\n` with `&&` in your startup script, not sure line-breaks are the correct way of chaining commands in this context. Separating commands with `&&` means the second command will run if the first command doesn't "fail" (exit with a code other than 0)

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington i tried with && but the html file is still not being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a startup-script, it runs as root.

So, firstly, the `sudo` is useless. Then, your `home` directory is `/root` and this directory is in write only. So, when you write your `index.html` file in the `/root` directory, it's impossible

Prefer a well known location, use `/tmp` for tests.

**AND** because you do write the file in `root` mode, the owner of the file will be `root` also. Perform a `chown` to change this if it's a blocker for the rest of your processes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the *shebang* at the start of the script to tell the operating system which interpreter to use. In your case that would be:

```
{
  ...
  "metadata": {
    "items": [
      {
       "key": "startup-script",
       "value": "#! /bin/bash\n\nsudo apt-get update\nexport DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive\necho "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1><p>This page was created from a startup script.</p></body></html>" > index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

It is essentially sending via API as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#providing_startup_script_contents_directly).

Note that you can troubleshoot startup scripts issues by checking Cloud Logging for that VM instance or in the the instance's serial console log directly.